# Table column slider alternation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a table with 4 columns, but only show 3 columns. So I would ideally have a div that spans the 3 columns and apply overflow: hidden. On a click of the button, I want column 3 (company 2) to slide left, and be replaced with column 4 (company 3), so that company 3 gets compared against company 1. If the button is clicked again, company 3 should slide left again, but company 2 should slide from the right and return to its original position as it was originally. The reason for doing this is because in mobile view we can't fit in all the columns.

Fiddle can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/smks/U7JHM/197/

HTML

```
<div class="div-table">
    <div class="div-table-row header-row">
        <div class="div-table-col header-row">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="div-table-col header-row">company 1</div>
        <div class="div-table-col header-row">company 2</div>
        <div class="div-table-col header-row">company 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-col">Comparison 1</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">yyy</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">yyy</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">yyy</div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-col">Comparison 2</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">yyy</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">www</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">yyy</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow">
        <div class="div-table-col">Comparison 3</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">uuu</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">Mkkk</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">yyy</div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<button>Compare Next</button>
```

CSS

```
.div-table{
  display:table;         
  width:auto;                 
  border:1px solid  #666666;         
  border-spacing:5px;/*cellspacing:poor IE support for  this*/
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.div-table-row{
  display:table-row;
  width:auto;
  clear:both;
  padding: 5px;
}
.div-table-col{
  float:left;/*fix for  buggy browsers*/
  display:table-column;         
  width:200px;  
  border:1px solid  #666666;
  padding: 5px;
}
.header-row {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty way - first I applied classes to the third and forth cols, and then animated the 4th one to hidden with a duration of 1 so it happens instantly. Then I toggle columns 3 and 4 each time the button is pressed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".c4").animate({
        width: 'toggle',
        opacity: 'toggle'
    }, 1); 
    $("button").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".c3, .c4").animate({
            width: 'toggle',
            opacity: 'toggle'
        });      
    });
});
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/U7JHM/202/

Comment: I'll give this a play. Although I could imagine them wanting more companies to compare. Thanks!